# Arbitrary/unknown output shape of Tensorflow conv2d_transpose

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Suppose I have a tensor of varying height, i.e. shape [batch_size=32, height=None, width=25, n_channels=128].  I'd like to upsample this tensor with the `conv2d_transpose` op, but I'm not sure how to generate the required `output_shape` argument.  With a known height, I'd do something like

```
def get_conv_transpose_shape(input, out_channels):
    out_shape = input.get_shape().as_list()
    out_shape[1] *= 2
    out_shape[2] *= 2
    out_shape[3] = out_channels
    return out_shape
```

But when height=None, this produces the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *= 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Is there a solution to this other than zero-padding all of my inputs to a standard size?  That's a computation cost I'd like to avoid.

Comment: When you call .get_shape().as_list(), you end up in "python land" trying to multiply a **None** with an **int**.Please try doing the operation in the symbolic domain, that is multiplying tensorflow.get_shape(input) with another symbolic variable of type float.

Comment: @rafaelvalle - could you promote your comment to an answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.get_shape().as_list()`, you end up in "static python land" trying to multiply a `None` with an `int`.

The operation should  be carried in the symbolic domain, that is multiplying `tensorflow.get_shape(input)` with another symbolic variable of type `int`.